# US J1 visa, port of entry different from final destination

Tags: j-visa, usa

I am going to San Francisco in January to study at UCB. I used to live for about a year in Boston some time ago. 
The visa starts mid-January.

Now, I would like to fly to Boston to meet up with old friends, enter the US there with my visa and then continue to SF a week later.

Would this pose a problem?

Comment: As long are you're entering the US not more than 30 days before the start date on your DS-2019, your port of arrival shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Dorothy in the comments:

> As long are you're entering the US not more than 30 days before the start date on your DS-2019, your port of arrival shouldn't be an issue.